# MySQL search text column

Tags: mysql

```
user_car
car_id      model_year      brand_id
1            2006               1
2            2010               3
3            2015               2
4            2015               1
5            2015               1
```

And

```
car_brand
brand_id        name
1               BMW
2               MAZADA
3               JEEP
```

> If I search "BMW2015" OR "2015BMW" OR "2015 BMW"

I can't get the result in above sql query, how can i search in proper way?

```
car_id  brand_id    model_year   name
4       1           2015         BMW
5       1           2015         BMW
```

Comment: you can try this 
SELECT * FROM  `my_table` WHERE  `description` LIKE  '2006%'

Comment: But my search keyword is "2006Pump" that's it.

Comment: you can try SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE description LIKE '%2006%'  or description LIKE  '%PUMP%'

Comment: `'%2006%Pump%'`

Comment: ok @Larry.He, it's right but It's ("2006Pump") my search string, not a constant value, And when i get a string so how can i identify different words and put "%" between us.

Answer (score 0):

If I search "BMW2015" OR "2015BMW" means you will be getting no rows only, if you search "BMW 2015" or "2015 BMW" means you manually split with " " and try the below query.

```
select * from user_car u inner join car_brand c on u.brand_id=c.brand_id where  model_year like "%2015%" or model_year like "%BMW%" or name like "%2015%" or or name like "%BMW%" group by car_id order by car_id
```

Comment: is it possible in one condition with one word not separated, also one more thing it's one table if i find a word in multiple tables with multiple columns so is it a proper way to get a result?

Comment: how many talbes you having, please explain your query. mysql not allowed  single word '%2006Pump%'  in multiple words

Comment: I edit my question, please check and give the solution.

Comment: It's not correct, how can i saperate word from string, because if i search "BMW2015" so how can i saperate, it's simple example not production example, please search in one condition not used to many "Or" "AND" query.

Comment: if i add one column decription in "user_car" table then how you manage?